# What is going wrong with my redis cache? Null response on a set key

Tags: node.js, typescript, caching, redis

I'm having a strange issue with my local redis cache and could use some help debugging. I'm attempting to store an object mapped to an id as key in my redis cache. I have a test file for the cache in which the tests for setting and getting object values work. When  I set the value against a key, I get no error messages. If I use `redis-cli` to monitor my redis DB I can see the set call with all my data. If I check the keys currently in my DB with `redis-cli`, I do not see the key. It is not expiring as the cache is set to expire in 1 hour. I see my get calls to redis with `redis-cli` monitor and that there is a `null` response, and can also see that it is definitely for the same key. Examples (obfuscated for bussiness security):

```
1695508290.121830 [0 127.0.0.1:62717] "set" 
"cache:CacheClass:fd3ac352f825aba7852adcb77a5613f11fea3d101cfd516c93cf07b9ac37c5cf" 
"{\"id\":\"e08f7b78-4f6e-415d-b03a-d0e68cecd0e7\",\
"userId\":\"me\",
\"location\":{\"latitude\":49.25228920000001,\"longitude\":-123.1222096}}" "PX" "3600"
```

Subsequent get call:

```
1695508305\.952736 \[0 127.0.0.1:62717\] "get" "cache:CacheClass:fd3ac352f825aba7852adcb77a5613f11fea3d101cfd516c93cf07b9ac37c5cf"
```

Subsequent calls to that key outside of the file it was set in fail and return null, HOWEVER calls to get the value on that key from within the file it is set in pass.

What gives? Its a really basic cache. I can provide more info on request. Implemented in TypeScript and env running on node 18.

I was expecting to be able to get the object from another file by calling the key. I tried switching my redis DB to 1 instead of 0 (all our redis functionality runs on DB 0), same issue. I've tried double checking the port and configuration, but it looks right to me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using an expire time for the key, the `PX` option. With `PX 3600` you say that the key will expire (and be deleted) in 3,6 seconds.